# Spring Batch Configuration without Pojo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I need to create a generic framework to Archive the Table and Put Archived data into CSV, For That we will have multiple table which we will be picking through config table in  Database, Now as we will have multiple tabes I don't want to write multiple reader  and writer and POJO specific to Table. I want to make it generic and I just need to enter new entry in our config table and my framework should do the work without doing any code changes.

My question is it feasible to achieve this without POJO in Spring Batch?

I have tried it using hashmap but the performance was very slow , I am open to enhance it further if can improve the performance else need a fresh suggestion.

Edit 1 : Select query will be picked from Config Table

Reader and Writer  which I have tried with Hashmap :

```
public ItemReader<Map<String, Object>> jdbcItemReader() {

        JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, Object>> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();

    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);

    reader.setSql("select a1,a2,a3 from Table");

    reader.setRowMapper(new ColumnMapRowMapper());

    return reader;

}


@Bean
public ItemWriter<Map<String, Object>> jdbcItemWriter() {

    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Map<String, Object>> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();

    writer.setDataSource(dataSource);

    writer.setSql(
                "INSERT INTO table1_hist (a1,a2,a3) VALUES (:a1,:a2, :a3)");
    writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Map<String, Object>>() {

        @Override
        public SqlParameterSource createSqlParameterSource(Map<String, Object> item) {
            MapSqlParameterSource mapSqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
            mapSqlParameterSource.addValues(item);
            return mapSqlParameterSource;
        }
    });
    return writer;

}
```

Edit 2 : Adding step and Job Configuration as well,

```
@Bean

public Step myStep(ItemReader<Map<String, Object>> reader, ItemWriter<Map<String, Object>> writer) {

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep")

            .<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>>chunk(10000)

            .reader(reader)

            .writer(writer)

            .build();

}

@Bean

public Job myJob(Step myStep) {

    return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
            .start(myStep)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Show your implementation.

Comment: @tgdavies I have added my implementation for reader and writer using Hashmap. 
I am exploring alternative approach, Also the select query will be differ for each table.

Comment: Show your job configuration, what is your chunk size, what is your fetch size (default JDBC fetch size is 10, set it to a 1000 or something like that). Finally have you considered **not using Spring Batch**? Are the tables in the same database? If so you might be better of with an `SELECT INTO` or an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement. Which saves you from transfering the data from the database to your java program and sending it back.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum , thanks for the suggestion , I have added Job configuration in the main question , I have explored other options but performance wise it was not that good and also spring batch provide an edge as we can write multiple writer , Even though tables are in same schema but I am not sure how we can pass the queries in a loop to reader and writer. If nothing works out then I will go ahead without using Spring Batch and will write custom framework

Comment: If you write a simple query you don't need Spring Batch. Just a simple `JdbcTemplate` it is just a simple query you need to execute. Something like `jdbcTemplate.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO history_table (x, y, z, a, b, c ) SELECT x, y, z, a ,b ,c FROM actual_table")`. Nothing more nothing less. No Spring Batch just what the database provides for you. You can quite easily call that in a loop, even on multiple threads if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are copying the data to a history table, which apparently are in the same schema I would suggest simply dropping Spring Batch and use the database for that. Using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` query, which does exactly that copy the data from one table to another.

As you are using Spring Boot you already have a pre-configured `JdbcTemplate` which you can use.

```java
var sql = "INSERT INTO table1_hist (a1,a2,a3) SELECT a1,a2,a3 FROM table1"
jdbcTemplate.executeUpdate(sql);
```

This will save you from transfering all the data from the database to your java program, construct an additional query and send all the data back to the database again. It will save you a lot of time on the network and executing single queries.

You could even execute this in a loop or make it multi threaded (1 for each table).

```java
public class DataArchiveService {

  private final JdbcTemplate jdbc;
  private final AsyncTaskExecutor executor;

  public DataArchiveService(JdbcTemplate jdbc, AsyncTaskExecutor executor) {
    this.jdbc=jdbc;
    this.executor=executor;
  }

  public void archive() {
    var archiveConfigs = // Get your metadata from somewhere
    for (var toArchive : archiveConfigs) {
      var sql = toArchive.getSql();
      executor.execute(() -> jdbc.executeUpdate(sql);
    }
  }
}
```

Now you have several threads running a, rather simple, query to copy the data. This should all be fairly quick, or at least quicker then anything you do on the Java side to transfer the data back and forth.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum going forward we need to convert archived data into CSV as well by writing one more writer in existing Batch that's why I have opt spring Batch , One part of my problem will solve this but I am exploring option through spring batch so that I will have flexibility to convert my historical data in CSV or XML or any other desired format.

Comment: Use Spring Batch to write the csv, use the query to copy. If you are writing simultaneously to JDBC and File your performance will be dictated by the writing speed to file, not so much the jdbc stuff. What you could do is place the code from this question in a `Tasklet` and place that in a first step. After that step finished do the writing to a csv (you could dump the history table to CSV).